# Using Spinner to change layouts

Tags: android

Using the below code I want to simply change layouts upon spinner value selection.  However, when my activity loads, the spinner never loads the values to be selected.

Oddly enough when I remove the code for (and everything below it)

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

the spinner values show up again.

```
public class ListCarsActivity extends Activity implements  OnItemClickListener, OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener {

public static final String TAG = "ListCarsActivity";
Spinner spinner;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_cars);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter adapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.domain,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    // initialize views
    initViews();

    }

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                                   int position, long row_id) {

            switch(position){
                case 1:
                    setContentView(R.layout.list_cars);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    setContentView(R.layout.list_owners);
                    break;
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.list_cars);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The spinner you are referring to is in your first activity. After you have replaced the content, the spinner isn't there anymore. If you have another spinner in the second layout, you have to reconnect it and set the listener again. Basically you have to run your onCreate stuff after every setContentView...

As a side note, whatever you are trying to do, this is probably not the way to go. To show another full layout, better use another activity.

Comment: So I should basically build a new activity for each spinner item? These are all going to be listviews for each new activity.  Can I re-use the same listview adapter? Since all the listviews are identical.